# Get Ethereum price with Uniswap on Graph Protocol

Tags: solidity

I'm learning Graph protocol and i was wondering if there was any way to get Ethereum price against USDC?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply look up the USDC and WETH balances of that Uniswap pair contract. The ratio will give you the 'spot' price of that market. Be aware that the actual price you get depends on the size of the trade, according to the constant product rule.